# jQuery.param unserialization in Python

Tags: python, post, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to unserialize complex data serialized via `jQuery.param()` function.

I've found the python library [jquery-unparam](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jquery-unparam/2.0.0) but unfortunately it doesn't manage well the kind of complex structure that can happens.

I've made an example that covers all the possibilities, here the data :

```
sample = {
    'some': 'value',
    'with': True,
    'but[]': ['contains', 'also', 'some', 'array'],
    'or[0]': 'even',
    'or[1]': 'numbered',
    'or[2]': 'arrays',
    'also[0][some]': 'with',
    'also[0][sub]': 'complex',
    'also[0][values]': 'structure',
    'and[finally]': 'some',
    'and[easier]': 'ones'
}
```

This data is the result from `request.form.to_dict()` in Flask. If you need it, here's the original value after beeing processed by `jQuery.param()` :

```
"some=value&with=true&but%5B%5D=contains&but%5B%5D=also&but%5B%5D=some&but%5B%5D=array&or%5B0%5D=even&or%5B1%5D=numbered&or%5B2%5D=arrays&also%5B0%5D%5Bsome%5D=with&also%5B0%5D%5Bsub%5D=complex&also%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D=structure&and%5Bfinally%5D=some&and%5Beasier%5D=ones"
```

Now, if you run the code from the Python library directly, you get this result:

```
{"and": {"finally": "some", "easier": "ones"}, "some": "value", "but": ["contains", "also", "some", "array"], "also": {"0": {"values": "structure", "some": "with", "sub": "complex"}}, "with": "true", "or": {"1": "numbered", "0": "even", "2": "arrays"}}
```

The thing is, the key `also` should be a list, not a dict, it should be like this:

```
{"and": {"finally": "some", "easier": "ones"}, "some": "value", "but": ["contains", "also", "some", "array"], "also": [{"values": "structure", "some": "with", "sub": "complex"}], "with": "true", "or": {"1": "numbered", "0": "even", "2": "arrays"}}
```

But I'm stuck at making this works.

Here's my code so far (changed from the library to work directly from Flask's to_dict code):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re, json


def parse_key_pair(key, val):
    groups = re.findall(r"\[.*?\]", key)
    groups_joined =  ''.join(groups)
    if key[-len(groups_joined):] == groups_joined:
        key = key[:-len(groups_joined)]
        for group in reversed(groups):
            if group == '[]':
                val = val
            else:
                # I've implemented this to transform to list, but the result is not good
                try:
                    int(group.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
                    val = [val]
                except ValueError:
                    val = {group[1:-1]: val}

    return {key: val}


def merge_two_structs(s1, s2):
    if isinstance(s1, list) and \
       isinstance(s2, list):
        return s1 + s2

    if isinstance(s1, dict) and \
       isinstance(s2, dict):

        retval = s1.copy()
        for key, val in s2.iteritems():
            if retval.get(key) is None:
                retval[key] = val
            else:
                retval[key] = merge_two_structs(retval[key], val)
        return retval
    return s2


def merge_structs(structs):
    if len(structs) == 0:
        return None
    if len(structs) == 1:
        return structs[0]
    first, rest = structs[0], structs[1:]
    return merge_two_structs(first, merge_structs(rest))


def parse_form(pair_strings):
    key_pairs = [parse_key_pair(x, pair_strings[x]) for x in pair_strings]
    return merge_structs(key_pairs)


sample = {
    'some': 'value',
    'with': True,
    'but[]': ['contains', 'also', 'some', 'array'],
    'or[0]': 'even',
    'or[1]': 'numbered',
    'or[2]': 'arrays',
    'also[0][some]': 'with',
    'also[0][sub]': 'complex',
    'also[0][values]': 'structure',
    'and[finally]': 'some',
    'and[easier]': 'ones'
}

print (json.dumps(parse_form(sample)))
```

If you can help me out on how to get a list instead of a dict for an array, it will be perfect!

Of course, if there is already an other library that does the job well, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the code above.

`request.form.to_dict()` doesn't do a proper representation of items passed via `"item[]=XXX&item[]=YYY"`. You'll get only one `item[]`...

So in order to fix this, I've rewritten the `to_dict()` to this:

```
from six import string_types

def convert_val(val):
    if not isinstance(val, string_types):
        return val
    elif val == '':
        return None
    elif val.lower() in ('false', 'true'):
        return True if val.lower() == 'true' else False
    if val[0:1] == '{':
        try:
            return json.loads(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val


def request_to_dict(params):
    result = {}
    for k in params:
        items = params.getlist(k)
        if len(items) == 1:
            result[k] = convert_val(items[0])
        else:
            result[k] = items

    return parse_form(result)
```

This returns a proper dictionnary parsing the specificities of the above sample, keeping the type whenever possible (boolean, integer, json, list or string) and is compatible for Python 2 and 3.